$\sum \frac{x}{n^{3/2} + n^{3/4} x^2}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$
Question: show that $\displaystyle\sum \frac{x}{n^{3/2}+n^{3/4}x^2}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.
My attempt: using the differentiation
$f_n’(x) = -\displaystyle\frac{x^2 - n^{3/4}}{n^{3/4}\left(x^2 + n^{3/4}\right)^2}$ which is $0$ if and only if
$x^2-n^{3/4}=0$.
This gave me that $x = n^{3/8}$.
So, sup_x ∈ [0,1] |f_n(n^(3/8)-0| and this led me to n^(3/8)/(2*n(3/2)) and as n approaches infinity, it converges to 0. Then therefore, it is uniformly convergent?
Is my process right? Did I correctly apply the differentiation of a power series here?

Welcome on MSE. I tried to make your question readable by editing it. Can you clarify what you meant when you computed $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\dots$? I can't see any equality signs, and the quantity you're computing the $\sup$ of doesn't seem to depend on $x$...

I was using iPad at that time posting it, it was sup subscript x where x element in [0,1]. I was looking for uniform convergence and this was the format.

Can you not verify normal convergence?
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\frac{x}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}+n^\frac{3}{4}x^2}\leq\frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}}$$

Your method is correct. The maximum of the absolute value of the $n$ term is equal $n^{3/8}/(2n^{3/2})=1/(2n^{9/8}).$ This estimate can be obtained with no differential calculus, as in the answer below.

Concerning the interval $[0,1]$ the $n$th term is bounded above by $1/n^{3/2}.$ Thus by the Weierstrass majorization theorem the series is convergent uniformly.
Actually the uniform convergence holds on the entire real line. Indeed applying $2ab\le a^2+b^2$ with $a=n^{3/4}$ and $b=n^{3/8}|x|$ yields $$ 2n^{9/8}|x|\le n^{3/2}+n^{3/4}x^2$$ Thus  the absolute value of $n$th term of the series is less than or equal $1/(2n^{9/8}). $  Hence the series is convergent absolutely and uniformly.
